# h264 Settings for Motion Tracking & Analysis (technical photography)?

Tags: framerate, h.264, motion, tracking, technical

I'm trying to do "scientific" video motion analysis. Right now I'm using a Raspberry Pi camera, which records natively in h264, which then needs to be converted/wrapped as MP4.

Is h264 an appropriate format for constant/fixed frame rate "progressive" images? I'm already noticing curvature of lines with motion, with the default settings.

Right now I'm using the open source [Tracker](https://tracker.physlets.org/) software to do the motion analysis.

What would be a good starting point for `raspivid` and `gpac` `MP4Box` settings, to get crisp "progressive" images (ie. full frame captures, with minimal compression/motion estimation), and preserving the frame rate through to the final MP4?

Or is a different capture format better for this purpose? Eventually I'd like to get high frame rate (~250 FPS or so) - low cost camera suggestions also appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is MPEG-2. For tracking and analysis, latency is the concern. H.264 is more complex than MPEG2, it introduces high latency as well. Since your content is not going to stream over network, i suggest MPEG-2

OpenCV always is the starting point, you may check https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/ and https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/30/opencv-object-tracking/

Good luck!